# > was not expected at this time (ERROR)

Tags: batch-file

So I'm creating an auto D'n'D character creator (Nerd Intensifies) and when writing stats to a text document none write and it displays "> was not expected at this time" for a split second

[Zip of the .bat files I'm using](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0q24eqo4om0mmwb/DNDmaker.zip)

Comment: I can't help because my employer blocks all file download sites.

Comment: Don't worry its pretty much fixed now. I learnt my lesson about send zips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing your zip file for viruses, because you should put the relevant code in your question and not tell people to download it, I immediately found it. You should append using only >>, and not >, >>, >>>. So instead of

```
echo %STR%>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %DEX%>>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %CON%>>>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %INT%>>>>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %WIS%>>>>>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %CHA%>>>>>>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %SPD%>>>>>>>>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
```

Just use

```
echo %STR%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %DEX%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %CON%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %INT%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %WIS%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %CHA%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
echo %SPD%>>"%~d0\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Character Maker\%NM%\%NM%.txt"
```

Next time when writing a question, try to find where the error occurs, and post the code needed to reproduce the error in your question.